# Access my application in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications

I have created an enviroment in Amazon using this link:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.quickstart.html

I did Step 1 (Create the Environment).
When I tried to find: "Publish to AWS" in visual studio (Step 2), I didn't find it.

So I thought to **upload and deploy** using Amazon (By Creating a zip file to my application).

I created a zip file to the the folders: App_Data, App_Starts, bin, Controllers, etc. all of the folders and files are found in one zip file.

This file was uploaded using: "Upload and Deploy":

[image]

When it finished (without errors), I entered the link to my environment:
XXX-env.elasticbeanstalk.com

And saw this page:
[image]

In localhost, I have the main controller with view: `/home`, So I tried:

XXX-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/home

But I got: **404 - File or directory not found.**

How Can I see my application in my amazon link?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue 1**

> I did Step 1 (Create the Environment). When I tried to find: "Publish to AWS" in visual studio (Step 2), I didn't find it.

You need to have the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio installed:

https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/

1. In the solution explorer, right-click on your web application.
2. Choose "Publish to AWS..." from the context menu.

**Issue 2**

> I created a zip file to the the folders: App_Data, App_Starts, bin, Controllers, etc. all of the folders and files are found in one zip file.

Simply creating a ZIP file of your project and assets won't work.

To properly deploy your application using the "Upload and Deploy" method, you should use the "Publish" function within Visual Studio.

1. Right click on your project and choose "Publish..." from the context menu.
2. Proceed through the wizard to create a publishing profile that creates a "Web Deploy Package".
3. Publish your project to your local hard disk. When you publish, you will create a ZIP file along with some helper files (.txt, .cmd, .xml, etc.).
4. Upload that generated ZIP file (the other files can be ignored) to Elastic Beanstalk and deploy it to your environment.

Comment: Thank you, good to know (both issues).
I tried both issues with no success. In issue 1: I downloaded the toolkit and install it. I closed the visual studio and opened again but "publish to AWS" didn't appear. So I tried issue 2: I followed step by step as you told and I still get 404 error (when navigating XXX...com/home

Comment: Maybe I need a real site name? although the publish succeeded (a zip was created) and the deploy succeeded (I uploaded this zip into amazon)

Comment: I succeeded! Thank you very much. I published it with debug mode instead of release. Sorry and thank you!